# Add autocomplete action to command line interface in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have a command line interface (polymer) that serves websites as an HTTP service.

To spin up a `localhost` service I can run `polymer serve`.

However, in the directory that I'm running there is a file called `service-worker.js` that it auto-completes to when a type `polymer` `[space]` `s + [tab]`.

Is there a way to add this command to this package so it autocompletes to `serve`?

Note: I am using `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, there is no (easy) way, because Zsh does not include completions for `polymer` and Polymer CLI itself does not install them either.

However, if you're willing to put some effort into it, then you could write a completion function for it yourself. For more info on this, read the following sections of the Zsh manual:

- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files
- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Functions-4
- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-Functions

Comment: Cool. Thanks Marlon!